# java RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA 256AndMGF1Padding equivalent in golang

Tags: java, go, cryptography

I'm trying to migrate some java encryption code into golang and came across this

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ECB_OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding);
          cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, cert);
          return cipher.wrap(key);
```

I'm trying to find any implementation of this in go. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptOAEP

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is a bit unclear I think you want a way to encode data in Go. You might find it helpful to google about the following standard Go packages:
`crypto/hmac`
`crypto/sha256`
`encoding/base64`

Comment: I updated the question. The first line in the code got omitted for some reason earlier.